Change in active constraints when perturbing the objective of a QP
Suppose I have a quadratic program (with positive semidefinite cost matrix) with affine (polytopic) constraints. It is known that the solution to this is piecewise affine, with the ``pieces'' defined in terms of the active constraints. I am trying to understand what happens to the minimizer when the cost matrix is perturbed a bit. To do so, we need to understand how the active constraints change. (Specifically, I wish to know if the minimizer is Lipschitz in the cost matrix. This extends the question asked in Sensitivity of the solution of QP with respect to parameters, which was about continuity.) Is there any pointer to this?
Thanks!
